# Can Changelings use oneiromancy for space travel?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, changeling-the-lost-2e

For example, if Changeling is on Mars, can they traverse Dream Roads to go to Earth?

Answer (score 4):

### That's not what oneiromancy does, and that's not where Changelings are.

Oneiromancy is the ability to travel through the realm of dreams. You can either get there by lucid dreaming (the Gate of Ivory) or by finding Dreaming Roads in the Hedge (the Gate of Horn). It's not a means of moving about reliably through the physical world.

Further, *Changeling: The Lost* takes place in the Chronicles of Darkness setting, on an Earth similar to our own (with some secrets and surprises). In the standard version of the game, there are no extra-planetary residents, so there would be no changelings on Mars, nor would there be dreamers on Mars for them to travel to.