# What are Dream Roads?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, changeling-the-lost-2e

I saw someone asking a question about Dream Roads, so I looked it up. But I can't find anything with 'Dream Roads' at all (well, that's related to what I'm looking for)! Just Plane of Dreams and stuff. What are Dream Roads? Also, it was Steve Redka who asked this question that got me wondering: [Can Changelings use oneiromancy for space travel?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/209017/can-changelings-use-oneiromancy-for-space-travel)

Comment: The tags on the linked question indicate it is about Changeling: The Lost second edition, so I’ve applied the appropriate tags for that game to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dreaming Roads (called Dream Roads in the linked question) are a concept in *Changeling: the Lost*, one of the game settings for Chronicles of Darkness.

In Changeling, you can play humans that were abducted by True Fae and turned into faerie creatures. These True Fae live in a place called Arcadia, which is separated from our everyday reality by a surreal land called The Hedge.

The Dreaming Roads are faerie roads that connect with the the world of dreams and lead through the Hedge. In the much more poetic words of *Changeling - The Lost* (p. 220):

> #### The Dreaming Roads
>
> The Hedge is the barrier separating stone and water
> from the fabric of unbound desires, and it has hidden
> paths that lead into dreams. These enchanted and furtive
> trods wend their way through wonders and perils, leading
> into dreamscapes just as the Hedge fades into Faerie.
> No one is certain why the Hedge connects to humanity’s
> dreams, other than to cite the uncanny similarities
> between its psychoactive properties and the human subconscious.
> These trods are the Dreaming Roads, and the
> fae know how to walk them into the dreams of Earth [...]
>
> The Dreaming Roads are mysterious avenues where
> escaped nightmares and shards of human fantasy roam,
> and so traversing one requires speed and attentiveness.

Comment: @Jadasc Thanks for the helpful edit. The reason why I had a bit of exposition for what Chronicles of Darkness /  World of Darkness is conceptually, as the asker is a 13 year old who seems to have not had any exposure to RPGs other than D&D (and barely that), and a game set in an alternate version of our reality is a bit different from one set in an entirely fantasy world. I thought that might be helpful to them to have as context.

Comment: To some degree, sure, but it ought to be the right game. Rein-Hagen's influence on CoD is comparable to Gygax's on 5e — in the past.